# Add a folder to the java.library.path in play framework using JNI

Tags: scala, playframework, java-native-interface

I want to use JNI with Play framework, finally following this project https://github.com/ezh/HelloWorldJNIwithRegisterNatives I managed to build the scala wrappers and compile the code, the library generated is working, but I need to change the java.library.path to point also to target/so where de library is generated, if not I need to copy manually it to one folder that is pointed by the java.library.path

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not your perfect solution but, if you want to execute some C/C++ source code from your backend (PlayFramework) I suggest you to compile your C/C++ source code giving an interface that you can call from shell.

Mkyong have a tutorial to execute shell commands from Java code:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("host -t a " + domain);
p.waitFor();

BufferedReader reader = 
     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";           
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good patch for the moment, so I up voted  your solution. But it is not the answer that I'm looking for. Cheers!